# Is it possible to disable GPU in kivy app?

Tags: kivy, gpu

I have developed a windows desktop application using kivy framework. Running standalone on a windows10 desktop the overall performance is OK. However, running the same app in a VMWare VDI Client the graphical performance is very bad. The resources assigned to the GPU are limited as you can see in the attached report.

Would it be possible to disable the GPU and to render the graphics in CPU? And if so, how to?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Kivy renders graphics using OpenGL. You do get software renderer implementations, but this is generally slow by nature, as OpenGL is designed for GPU rendering. I doubt you would find that it helped your Kivy app much, if at all. If you do want to try, I don't know exactly what you'd need to do, but getting Kivy to run via an OpenGL software renderer would be the basic idea.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your comment. It sounds a like a tough job. So I will first ask the infrastructure guys to extend the GPU config. That should help anyway. However, for over 1000 end-users this might become quite expensive....

Comment: Kivy shouldn't actually need all that much from the gpu, what it does is fairly trivial compared to things like fancy games.